# Creating ROI mask by using drawContours in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am using drawContours to make a mask for extracting ROI.

I have already defined four points and a zero mask for drawing the contour.

The output mask of the drawContours function is sort of a trapezoid shape which is what I want.

However, when I use this mask to do bitwise_and with the image,
the result isn't really the same shape with the mask.

The edge of the shape is obviously jagged.

Here is my python code snippet:

```
hull2 = cv2.convexHull(crop1)
mask10 = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype = "uint8")
print(len(hull2))
cv2.drawContours(mask10, [hull2], -1,255, -1,cv2.LINE_AA)   


cv2.imshow("mask10",mask10)
cv2.waitKey(0)
crop = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask10)



cv2.imshow("crop",crop)
cv2.waitKey(0) 
cv2.drawContours(image, [hull2], -1, (0, 255, 0), -1,cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow("mask+img",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

And here is a picture showing the result: ["crop" is the ROI result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fgqj.jpg)

Thanks for anyone trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting jagged edges while your mask looks like it has smooth edges is because you are using the anti-aliasing flag on drawContours( - ,cv2.LINE_AA) which fills in the surrounding of the jagged edges with darker pixels creating a gradient that fools your eye into thinking its a smooth edge.

Why does this matter? when you use bitwise_and with a mask, any value in the mask greater than 0 is evaluated as "True" and the corresponding pixel in the image will be selected. 
So those extra AA pixels despite being a smaller gray value than 255, are expanding the edge of the mask, creating your jagged edge in crop. To emulate this, do mask10[mask10 > 0] = 255; cv2.imshow('mask10', mask10) and it should have the same shape as crop.

Now as a possible solution to your problem, you could use alpha blending to use the gradient (darkened intensity) of those extra AA pixels to darken the crop image edge pixels.

```
mask_float = cv2.cvtColor(mask10, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR).astype('float32') / 255
image_float = image.astype('float32')
crop = cv2.multiply(image_float, mask_float).astype('uint8')
```

First we convert mask10 to a 3 channel array so that we can apply the alpha blending to all 3 BGR channels of the image.

Then we normalize the mask to a [0-1] range as we will need to multiply the values in the next step and dtype uint8 doesnt allow greater than 255. So first converting to float32 then dividing by 255. (we could potentially use cv2.normalize() but numpy should be alot faster)

we then convert the image to float32 to allow for multiplication with the mask.

then we multiply the image with the mask to get an alpha blended image of foreground to a black background and convert it back to uint8 for opencv.

Now since the BGR values are converted from float32 to uint8, it will discard the decimal values which will cause a negligible change in color. Also, I'm not 100% sure but there might be a small change in color due to multiplying each channel individually by the same value (eg: 20%) or it could be fine and im just overthinking it? But that only applies to those darkened AA pixels, the effect should also be negligible and we are already modifying it from the original anyways so it should be fine!

As an alternative, you could also convert the image to HLS and multiply the mask to the L-channel only. I believe that should be more true to the image's colors on those edges if that is very important, and the slower speed is permissible

Comment: You taught me a lesson and solved my problem.Thank you so much. 
But  based on your explanation, I found it's easier to do mask10[mask10 <255] = 0